# Use AWK to extract just the MAC addresses from a show mac address-table from a cisco switch

Tags: macos, csv, awk

I'd need to take the output from a `show mac address-table` on a Cisco switch and extract only the Mac addresses and put them in a CSV file.

The output looks like this

```
vlan     Mac Address     Type    Ports
-----    -----------     -----    -----
All      0011.2233.4455  STATIC   CPU
All      0011.2233.4466  STATIC   CPU
All      0011.2233.4477  STATIC   CPU
All      0011.2233.4488  STATIC   CPU
```

Macs are displayed in groups of 4 as seen above. I need to grab each MAC address and output it to a csv file.

This works but it also grabs unwanted output.

```
awk '{print $2}' macTable.log > macTable.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add a condition that the field only contains digits and dots:

```
awk '$2~/^[0-9.]+$/{print $2}' macTable.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test for the two  types of mac-address `STATIC` and `DYNAMIC`

```
awk 'tolower($3)~/static|dynamic/ {print $2}' log
0011.2233.4455
0011.2233.4466
0011.2233.4477
0011.2233.4488
```

PS you need to use `tolower` since switch may use uppercase and routers uses lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with grep:

```
egrep -o '([0-9]{4}\.){2}[0-9]{4}'
```

Output:

```
0011.2233.4455
0011.2233.4466
0011.2233.4477
0011.2233.4488
```